# How to check if window is really visible in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms, screen

Normally you use Form.Visible to check if Window is visible at all. But sometimes on the screen window is below other windows so it's really invisible.

So how to check in c# Windows Forms if window is really visible or not?

I would like to accomplish this: when I click CTRL+K on my keyboard and my window is visible on my screen it does nothing. But when it's underneath other windows it pops to the top (Bring to front).

kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the [`Activate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activate.aspx) method on the form to bring it to the front if it isn't already.

However, note that if a different program is active, it will usually simply flash the desktop button (depending where you call it from).  This is Windows' [standard protection against focus-stealing](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx) and you [should not try to work around it](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

I googled trough the web, but coudn't find any straight answer to see if a part of a window is truly visible to the user. I actually needed a way to "hittest" the form, if the mouse is currently on top of the visible part of the window. I thought I'd share the code which took several days to accomplish:

```
public class VisibilityTester
{
    private delegate bool CallBackPtr(int hwnd, int lParam);
    private static CallBackPtr callBackPtr;

    /// <summary>
    /// The enumerated pointers of actually visible windows
    /// </summary>
    public static List<IntPtr> enumedwindowPtrs = new List<IntPtr>();
    /// <summary>
    /// The enumerated rectangles of actually visible windows
    /// </summary>
    public static List<Rectangle> enumedwindowRects = new List<Rectangle>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Does a hit test for specified control (is point of control visible to user)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ctrlRect">the rectangle (usually Bounds) of the control</param>
    /// <param name="ctrlHandle">the handle for the control</param>
    /// <param name="p">the point to test (usually MousePosition)</param>
    /// <param name="ExcludeWindow">a control or window to exclude from hit test (means point is visible through this window)</param>
    /// <returns>boolean value indicating if p is visible for ctrlRect</returns>
    public static bool HitTest(Rectangle ctrlRect, IntPtr ctrlHandle, Point p, IntPtr ExcludeWindow)
    {
        // clear results
        enumedwindowPtrs.Clear();
        enumedwindowRects.Clear();

        // Create callback and start enumeration
        callBackPtr = new CallBackPtr(EnumCallBack);
        EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr.Zero, callBackPtr, 0);

        // Go from last to first window, and substract them from the ctrlRect area
        Region r = new Region(ctrlRect);

        bool StartClipping = false;
        for (int i = enumedwindowRects.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (StartClipping && enumedwindowPtrs[i] != ExcludeWindow)
            {
                r.Exclude(enumedwindowRects[i]);
            }

            if (enumedwindowPtrs[i] == ctrlHandle) StartClipping = true;
        }

        // return boolean indicating if point is visible to clipped (truly visible) window
        return r.IsVisible(p);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Window enumeration callback
    /// </summary>
    private static bool EnumCallBack(int hwnd, int lParam)
    {
        // If window is visible and not minimized (isiconic)
        if (IsWindow((IntPtr)hwnd) && IsWindowVisible((IntPtr)hwnd) && !IsIconic((IntPtr)hwnd))
        { 
            // add the handle and windowrect to "found windows" collection
            enumedwindowPtrs.Add((IntPtr)hwnd);

            RECT rct;

            if (GetWindowRect((IntPtr)hwnd, out rct))
            {
                // add rect to list
                enumedwindowRects.Add(new Rectangle(rct.Left, rct.Top, rct.Right - rct.Left, rct.Bottom - rct.Top));
            }
            else
            {
                // invalid, make empty rectangle
                enumedwindowRects.Add(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        return true;
    }


    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsIconic(IntPtr hWnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int EnumDesktopWindows(IntPtr hDesktop, CallBackPtr callPtr, int lPar);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
        public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
        public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
        public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Left + "," + Top + "," + Right + "," + Bottom;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use Windows API to enumerate all windows, retrieve their Z-Order and compare it with the Z-Order of your window. I think someone did this already [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/Is_My_Application_on_Top_.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question as asked, you could try calling the [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx) API function to find the window at various points on your form, and check whether it returns the handle of whatever you expect to be at that point.

Comment: This is the best answer for me after scouring the web and SO. SLaks to the rescue! That SO cred speaks for itself.

Answer (score 2):

I aktually tried to implement SLaks suggestion. Although I wrote it in VB.NET, not C#

```
Friend Structure PointStruct
    Public x As Int32
    Public y As Int32
End Structure

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Friend Function WindowFromPoint(ByVal Point As PointStruct) As IntPtr
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Checks if a control is actually visible to the user completely
''' </summary>
''' <param name="control">The control to check.</param>
''' <returns>True, if the control is completely visible, false else.</returns>
''' <remarks>This is not 100% accurate, but feasible enough for my purpose.</remarks>
Public Function IsControlVisibleToUser(ByVal control As Windows.Forms.Control) As Boolean
    If Not control.Visible Then Return False

    Dim bAllPointsVisible As Boolean = True
    Dim lPointsToCheck As New List(Of Point)
    'Add the points to check. In this case add the edges and some border points
    'between the edges.
    'Strangely, the exact edge points always return the false handle.
    'So we add a pixel into the control.
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Left + 1, control.Top + 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Right - 1, control.Top + 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Right - 1, control.Bottom - 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Left + 1, control.Bottom - 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Left + control.Width / 2, control.Top + 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Right - 1, control.Top + control.Height / 2))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Right - control.Width / 2, control.Bottom - 1))
    lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Left + 1, control.Bottom - control.Height / 2))
    'lPointsToCheck.Add(New Point(control.Left + control.Width / 2, control.Top + control.Height / 2))

    'Check each point. If all points return the handle of the control,
    'the control should be visible to the user.
    For Each oPoint In lPointsToCheck
        Dim sPoint As New PointStruct() With {
            .x = oPoint.X, _
            .y = oPoint.Y _
        }
        bAllPointsVisible = bAllPointsVisible And ( _
            (WindowFromPoint(sPoint) = control.Handle) _
        )
    Next

    Return bAllPointsVisible
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could.. :) get the ClickablePoint property from the AutomationElement corresponding to the window.
I am not 100%ly sure whether this is completely accurate though.. it has worked in 99% of the cases for me and I am still checking on the other 1%, where the problem lies (might be on my side or bad user handling, or.)

Answer (score 0):

Hm... weird question. :P

Perhaps you could ask the location of the forms, and if two forms interlap (figure out their coords, and make a simple method) check if one form has Focus(). If it has focus, then other must be "invisible" (*in the sense that a user can't see it because it's underneath the other form*).

Obviously this method is hacky **at best**, but it's something you can start working with.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find out if your window is visible by overriding the OnPaint method.  You'll want to pass control to the base class in order to do the actual painting, but you'll be able to detect whether a paint message is received.
Update: no, this doesn't work,  Sorry!

In principle, the Activate method should bring your window to the foreground, but in practice I've always found this problematic if other processes have the input focus.  If you really want someone to see a window, set the topmost bit, but expect them to be annoyed!  One surefire way to get some attention for a window is to close it and reopen it, if you can get away with that.

One way to achieve what you're looking for is to use a notify icon, this will get the user's attention in a way that is compliant with Windows UI guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified C# version of the code in [@MarvinDickhaus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649959/how-to-check-if-window-is-really-visible-in-windows-forms#16760756).

It allows to test if a window or any control is visible or partially visible by checking only certain points.

The main basic interest is to be able to bring to front a fully or partially covered form.

It uses 13 points but more can be added, and the method can be improved to pass an arbitrary number and calculate the coordinates from that number. The default margin is set to 15 for Windows 10 forms.

```
static partial class NativeMethods
{
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
  public struct PointStruct
  {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public PointStruct(int x, int y)
    {
      X = x;
      Y = y;
    }
  }
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static public extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(PointStruct Point);
}
```

```
static public IEnumerable<T> GetAllControls<T>(this Control control)
{
  var controls = control.Controls.OfType<T>();
  return control.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                         .SelectMany(c => c.AllControls<T>())
                         .Concat(controls);
}
```

```
static public List<Point> GetGridPoints(this Control control, int margin = 15)
{
  int widthDiv2 = control.Width / 2;
  int heightDiv2 = control.Height / 2;
  int widthDiv4 = widthDiv2 / 4;
  int heightDiv4 = heightDiv2 / 4;
  var points = new List<Point>();
  // Center
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + widthDiv2, control.Top + heightDiv2));
  // Corners
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + margin, control.Top + margin));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Right - margin, control.Top + margin));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + margin, control.Bottom - margin));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Right - margin, control.Bottom - margin));
  // Borders
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + widthDiv4, control.Top + heightDiv4));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Right - widthDiv4, control.Top + heightDiv4));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + widthDiv4, control.Bottom - heightDiv4));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Right - widthDiv4, control.Bottom - heightDiv4));
  // Inner
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + widthDiv2, control.Top + margin));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + widthDiv2, control.Bottom - margin));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Left + margin, control.Top + heightDiv2));
  points.Add(new Point(control.Right - margin, control.Top + heightDiv2));
  return points;
}
```

```
static public bool IsVisibleOnTop(this Control control, int requiredPercent = 100, int margin = 15)
{
  if ( !control.Visible ) return false;
  var controls = control.GetAllControls<Control>().Select(c => c.Handle).ToList();
  var points = control.GetGridPoints(margin);
  bool all = requiredPercent == 100;
  int found = 0;
  int required = points.Count();
  if (!all) required = required * requiredPercent / 100;
  foreach ( var point in points )
  {
    var handle = NativeMethods.WindowFromPoint(new NativeMethods.PointStruct(point.X, point.Y));
    if ( handle == control.Handle || controls.Contains(handle) )
    {
      if ( ++found == required ) return true;
    }
    else
    {
      if ( all ) return false;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Simply set the `Form.AlwaysOnTop` property to `true`.

Comment: Won't help if another window also has the same property