# How do you tell if a Windows Form is open but behind another window?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-2.0, form-control

Calling Form.Visible will return true regardless of whether the form is maximized, minimized, or has a FormWindowState of Normal.

What I want to know is how to tell if the form is open but "hidden" behind another application's window.

If that's the case, I want to bring it to the front and actually make it visible to the user.

I tried the BringToFront() method but it didn't work. I also tried calling the Show() method but if the form is behind another application's window, it remains that way.

The only workaround I found to the problem is setting the Form's FormWindowState to Minimized/Maximized and then normal, but that's a bit of a hack and doesn't look nice.

Can someone tell me how to tell if the form is behind another window and how to bring it to the front?

Comment: Did you try the `.Activate()` method?

Comment: Actually, I just tried the Activate() method and it did work. Now I have a way to bring the window to the front. Thanks! But there is still one question unanswered: how do you tell if the window is actually visible to the user?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strange.

`this.Activate()` should do the trick.

You can always try a 'horrible hack method', which I feel guilty for spreading. But if `this.Activate()` doesn't work, for the sake of testing you might try:

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.Focus();
this.BringToFront();
this.TopMost = false;
```

I've never seen this recommended as a solution, but it might work to show you the functionality. I'd be more concerned about why `this.Activate()` isn't working if the above-mentioned code does.

As for detecting the window, you cannot use a command to detect it via C# like that. Check the following questions answers for more info: 
[How to check if window is really visible in Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649959/how-to-check-if-window-is-really-visible-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Sorry, he posted that after I had typed this up. Deciding to leave it posted in case others come by and see it and can't get this.Activate() to work.

Comment: Updated the end of my question to show the other stack question about detecting the window z-position

Answer (score 2):

Try to wire below,

```
private void frmMyForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Raise your flag here.
    }
```

By wiring above event, it will tell you whenever the form is minimized, partially/totally hided by another form.

Answer (score -1):

Well, as you know, windows might or might not have `Focus`. If a windows is focused, it is therefore that the user have clicked it. You can try the `Focused` property. Otherwise, I don't think there is a property which tells you if another window is above yours.
You can "give" focus, therefore "popping out" the window with the `Focus()` method.

Note: A window can be both focused *and* be under another window. 
To determine if your window isn't under another window, I'm afraid you must go deeper.