# Get windows that are on top of form

Tags: c#, winforms

Wonder if there is a way to check if an application is on top of my form?

For example if you open up your form, and then open up 2 other windows(like music player and web browser), and to list these windows?

Comment: You can check if your form has `Focus` (but this might not be totally correct)

Comment: you could check for focus pretty easily, but that's not exactly the same thing

Comment: with questions like these, my question is always "Why?"  can you do it?  you can use native win32 apis to enumerate all windows and find those which overlap yours, yes.  but what would you do then?  what are you *actually* trying to do?  Do you want to force yours to be always on top?  do you simply want to bring yours to the front?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: gunr2171, Jonesy, no its not what i mean but thanks.
Habib, not a duplicate at all, but thanks.
John, Why do you care? :) I have my own program, which needs this part to work correctly. If you would not like to help, then just leave the posts alone, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That standard way would be to

1. Get your window's bounding box as a rectangle.
2. Get your window's location on the Z-axis.
3. Find all open windows with a Z-axis location higher than yours (which see the answer by @ReedCopsey above).
4. For each such window, determine if its bounding box intersects yours. See:

   - [Two Rectangles intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390333/two-rectangles-intersection)
   - [Algorithm to detect intersection of two rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115426/algorithm-to-detect-intersection-of-two-rectangles)

   for a discussion of the algorithm. Or let the CLR do the work for you using the [`System.Windows.Rect.Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.rect_methods.aspx) overloads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this seems to be the most complete answer, so i accept this one, just meanwhile, i found an easier way to do what id like to. Thanks anyway, caz i might need this later!

Answer (score 0):

> For example if you open up your form, and then open up 2 other windows(like music player and web browser), and to list these windows?

You could P/Invoke [`EnumWindows`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx).  This will return the list of windows *in z order*.

As soon as your `Form` is found, you'd know you no longer have to continue searching.  All windows you found prior to your window Handle would be "above" your Form in the z order.

If you're only interested in windows which *overlap* yours, you'd have to check their position and size as well.

Comment: that gets them in z order, but not whether they are overlapping, correct?  you'd have to do extra work to compare window bounds/etc?

Comment: @JohnGardner Yes - see the last paragraph ;)

Comment: You could combine this with some changes to my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860247/how-can-i-check-if-a-form-is-behind-another-window/18876823#18876823