# Check form that it is behind other windows

Tags: c#

I have a main and a secondary form. When I click on secondary form then the main form loses the focus. So I restore the focus with this.Focus(). It is OK.

The problem is when the main form is behind other program windows (not on taskbar, just behind). In this case I do not want restore the focus to main form.

But I don not know how can I check the visibility of main form? Visible, or behind other programs?

Comment: I don't understand why when you click one form, you'd want to set focus to the other. How do you ever get focus on the secondary form? By hiding the main form? What if the main form is positioned off the edge of the monitor? What if it's minimized?

Comment: @itsme86 When I click on the secondary form then some operation is completed and secondary get the focus. After all operation I need to restore the focus on main form.

Comment: Ahhhh. I see now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649959/how-to-check-if-window-is-really-visible-in-windows-forms might be helpful.